# SAPUI5 using chart.js

Tags: javascript, charts, sapui5, chart.js

Is it possible to use SAPUI5 together with chart.js and also use a odatamodel as input for the chart?
Would be also nice if there are any example how to implement it.

I know UI5 has also possibility to plot charts but the are very poor.

I want plot a chart with different background color to higlight some data.
Similar to this [image]

Comment: You can simply create a custom control which embeds the chart from the 3rd party library you want to display, and use standard databinding to populate the chart. Have a look at for instance the Walkthrough: https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/docs/guide/d12d2ee6a5454d799358d425f9e7c4db.html

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question: It is possible and a similar implementation was made in the past.

I'm reffering to [SAPUI5 custom controls](https://github.com/jay-sdk/sapui5-custom-controls) which implemented a subset of d3.js on which chart.js is based. Since this implementation is two years old, it probably won't work with the most recent UI5 version (1.34.6), but there is definitly some value for your implementation in reading the code and the [SCN article](http://scn.sap.com/community/developer-center/front-end/blog/2014/07/17/custom-sapui5-visualization-controls-with-d3js) for it.

I won't share an implementation example here since it would require a complete implementation of a custom element like Qualiture mentioned.